# How to pass multiple parameters using html link in Struts1.x

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to my Struts action class using `<html:link>` property.

I am having a link, it should take two parameters from the JSP page to my action class.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In Struts 1.3 parameters could be set to the `action` attribute like in this example

```
<html:link action="/path/to/action?param1=2&param2=${param2Value}">Some text</html:link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3alink):

> If you prefer to specify a java.util.Map that contains all of the request parameters to be added to the hyperlink, use one of the following techniques:
>
> - Specify only the name attribute - The named JSP bean (optionally scoped by the value of the scope attribute) must identify a java.util.Map containing the parameters.
> - Specify both name and property attributes - The specified property getter method will be called on the bean identified by the name (and optional scope) attributes, in order to return the java.util.Map containing the parameters.
>
> As the Map is processed, the keys are assumed to be the names of query parameters to be appended to the hyperlink. The value associated with each key must be either a String or a String array representing the parameter value(s), or an object whose toString() method will be called. If a String array is specified, more than one value for the same query parameter name will be created.
>
> Supplmenting these two methods, you can nest one or more  tags to dynamically add parameters in a logic-friendly way (such as executing a for loop that assigns the name/value pairs at runtime). This method does not compete with the aforementioned; it will adds its parameters in addition to whatever parameters are already specified.

You can also use a regular HTML `<a>` tag and create the URL using the standard `<c:url>` tag from the JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you go with ajax calling ? by using ajax you can pass many parameter to action class by set the method K

Comment: doesn't answer the user's question